# Installing a plugin manually in Websphere Commerce RAD 7.5 / Eclipse 3.4.2?

Tags: websphere-commerce

I am trying to install FindBugs manually on IBM RAD 7.5. Unfortunately it's too old to use the automated plugin installer, and so I am trying to do it manually.

WebSphere creates a LOT of directories named "plugins". Which is the right one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the setenv.bat file. Run it. Check what the environment variable RAD_HOME is set to. Your plugins live in %RAD_HOME%\dropins\wcde\eclipse\plugins.

For an example/test, try installing CheckStyle using these instructions: http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/downloads.html